# How to Create a Tar GZip File from the Command Line

Tags: macos, gzip, tar

I was able to create gzip file using the below command but my files are not directly under gzip file.

tar -cvzf destfile.tgz /Users/Desktop/package/

When it creates destfile.tgz it has the folder structure /Users/Desktop/package/ inside it . But i want files of my package folder  directly under destfile.tgz.  Is there way we can modify it to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest:

```
cd /Users/Desktop/package/
tar -cvzf ../destfile.tgz *
```

Comment: Even [more](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168357/creating-a-tar-archive-without-including-parent-directory/168362#168362).